# Compiz not working in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, compiz

I can't get any features of compiz desktop effects working on a fresh install of Karmic Koala. I've uninstalled and reinstalled with sudo apt-get remove compiz and uninstalled advanced desktop settings through the software center. I am completely up to date.

Thanks

Comment: yes. it's a nVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 260M

Comment: I have also noticed that my windows seem very sluggish. I'm not sure if this is related or should be addressed separately. It could be due to docky, which has also given me issues. I fear that the best option is a reinstall but this is already my second attempt. P.S. nevermind this, a test with a window manager in a panel seems to have proven the fault of the lag is docky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

needed to update my restricted drivers.